# Bootstrap:Multiple page navigation within a modal

Tags: navigation, pagination, bootstrap, modal

I am working on a sprint management tool.The scrum master gets to select from a list of bugs available to him.

Once he selects and hits 'Add bugs' - he needs to provide the justification individually for adding each bug.

I am planning to do this via a **single modal** ***(Bootstrap 2.3.2)***

[Suppose he selects 5 bugs to add] -

- Now a modal pops up which will have 5 pages - one page for each bug
- Each page should show the details of a bug and take in the justification.
- Then he goes to the next page(bug) within the same modal.
- After such 5 pages - he will get a submit option.

I am not sure if this(multiple pages within a given modal) is possible(any pointer on how to setup a multiple page modal will be great help).

Need critique/advice if this is a decent enough UI approach to glean the information.If no - Any alternative UI suggestion/s will do a lot in clearing the air up for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ***how***, it is certainly possible and there are a number of templates and patterns for doing so available, [such as this one](https://github.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal). In that example you could use "Bug X" instead of "Step X" in your headers and you'd have a nice step-by step modal with a progress bar to show the SCRUM master his progress.

As for the question of ***should you*** the primary consideration when it comes to Modals is "is it critical that this gets done". Modals are essentially a way of trapping the user and saying "you can't do anything else until you do this". You need to think if that is **really what you mean** to say.

Ask yourself if there are any other options you want to have available to the user once they click that button. Should they be able to go back and add more bugs? Will they be able to cancel adding bugs? Is there anything they may want/need to edit in the bug before they justify it?

If you mean to force the user to complete the task once they start then you should be safe with the Modal, that's what they're intended for. If you're not sure you may want to look at these [alternative design patterns](https://developer.appway.com/screen/ShowSingleRecipe/selectedRecipeId/1390246496349) instead.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, your approach is way too convoluted and has a lot of friction. Having a modal with inner navigation (or a *stepper*) and then a submit button only after all steps were completed is asking for trouble.

First of all, when you use a modal, you use to interrupt a flow and require an action based on the context. If you have multiple actions, you're losing focus on **why** and **how** the user got there in the first place.

On top of that, what happens if the user gets to **step 4**, then realizes **step 1** was wrong? s/he will probably close the modal and will need to do all again. OR, user will freak out because s/he won't want to lose all the information.

**In short:** this is not an appropriate way to do things by any means.

## Alternative

Try using inline editing by simply adding an **edit icon** on each row (and **delete** if appropriate) . This way user will know the changes will affect ONLY one item and nothing else, and will always be on control of the information provided.